# Overridden clean function not being called

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

The documentation says (which I have done)

> The clean_() method is called on a form subclass – where
>    is replaced with the name of the form field attribute.

Next it is telling me that I should do (I believe I have done so)

> You will need to look up the value of the field in self.cleaned_data

My Form

```
class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'title', 'text', 
        )

        def clean_text(self):
            data = self.cleaned_data['text']
            print(data)

            #check if word count is <30
            if len(data.split()) < 30:
                raise forms.ValidationError(('Please write at least 30 words,\
                                    %(count)s words is not long enough'), params={'count':count})
            return data
```

My View

```
@login_required
def create_new_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.created = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CreatePostForm()
    return render(request, 'journal/create_post.html', {'form':form})
```

So I tried printing to see if the function is even being called, but nothing was being printed in the console.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect. At the moment, `clean_text` is a method of the `Meta` class.

```
class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'title', 'text', 
        )

        def clean_text(self):
            ...
```

It should be indented at the *same* level as the `Meta` class:

```
class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'title', 'text', 
        )

    def clean_text(self):
        ...
```